# Niederlassungserlaubnis validity when living in Germany 2 days a week

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, residency

I am non-EU Person living in Germany and having a Niederlassungserlaubnis. I have got a Job Offer in United Kingdom which means i will working in UK with a UK work Contract for the week and returning to DE for the weekend.

What implication will this have on my Niederlassungserlaubnis ? I know for a fact that i must live in Germany for at least 6 months in a year otherwise my Niederlassungserlaubnis will get expired and as all the weekends in the year don't sum-up to 6 months but as i am returning to Germany every week will it still get expired ?

Comment: For clarity, what will your immigration status be in the UK? What type of work visa will you have?

Comment: I do not really know the answer to that right now. I am assuming some kind of standard visa for work i guess.

Comment: There are several types of work visa, depending on the nature and length of the job. You can check which one you’ll need here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Comment: Could you find a solution? I am in a similar situation.

Answer (score -3):

Good question and one that will not have a straightforward answer.

This is a case where you must ask the Immigration office directly, preferably in a **detailed** letter with information on expected income and costs (double household and travel costs).

Since you are retaining your household in Germany and returning regularly, the result *could* be a letter confirming the arrangement and that they have no objection to it.

This would then be the equivalent of a permission to be absent longer than the default 6 months, which should be applied for before the arrangement starts.

This will be a matter that the responsible official will deside based on the individual circumstances and thus it will be impossible to foretell what the final outcome will be.

Comment: (-1) That's terrible advice. The more ambiguous the situation, the less advisable this course of action. If this is indeed up to the immigration office and it requires prior permission (it's not clear to me that it would be and you have presented no reason to believe it is), what you want is a competent lawyer to draft a letter stating why they should give you that permission, not volunteer random facts that could lead to an adverse decision.

Comment: @Relaxed The lawyer will do exactly the same thing, send a detailed letter with all relevant information and await their reply and pass that on. The same effect, but less costly. As stated in the answer, this must be done before the arrangement starts, thus a refusal will have no negative effect.

Comment: That means there is unfortunately no clear cut answer to my question.

Comment: @MarkJohnson You seem generally confused on what lawyers actually do and how to deal with immigration issues. A lawyer will analyse the situation, they are best positioned to know which facts are relevant, should have a good idea of the most likely outcome and advice on how to change the situation if that's needed. Officials won't do that for you, you should never approach them before you have done that. That's very different from what you are recommending.

Comment: A lawyer will then build an argument, present relevant facts in a good light, avoid volunteering information that doesn't need to be, and make sure to include everything you need to prepare an appeal, if that turns out to be necessary. That's also very different from a letter listing disconnected facts and hoping for the best.